# Can I convert any matrix to triangular form and still maintain its characteristic polynomial?

Tags: matrices, number-theory

If I change a matrix in any way (i.e. to another form), does that change the underlying characteristic polynomial? The characteristic polynomial of a triangular matrix is computed with the diagonal alone, so I am wondering if I can convert to triangular and then use the diagonal to get the characteristic polynomial, or if I would be computing something else entirely as a result of the conversion.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I do not quite understand, is this like triangular form that preserves the polynomial?

Comment: Yes it is, because the Jordan normal form is given by $A=P J P^{-1}$, and for any transformation of such a kind (conjugations) the characteristic polynomial is preserved.

Comment: Anyway there is no hope to compute the characteristic polynomial from the diagonal alone: if it was possible, any matrix would be diagonalizable (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use, for example, Gaussian method to reduce the matrix to an upper triangular form, then, essentially, you pass from matrix $A$ to a matrix $PA$ where $P$ is a non-singular matrix. The characteristic polynomials of $PA$ and $A$ are, in general case, different and have no common eigenvalues.

To illustrate, take a non-singular matrix $A$ with strictly imaginary eigenvalues. By Gaussian elimination we arrive to an upper-triangular real matrix which has only real eigenvalues (its diagonal elements, to be precise). The set of eigenvalues being different, the characteristic polynomials are also different.

However, similar matrices ($A=P^{-1}BP$ with non-singular $P$) have the same characteristic polynomials (easy to check by definition).

Comment: So in other words I can't do this?

Comment: @user226947 no, you can't. I'd formulate it as "The class of matrices where you can do that, is very, very narrow".